# How to change default push notification icon to small icon in Onesignal in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, onesignal

I have a problem to change small icon push notification Onesignal in ionic 3, I have tried this tutorial https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/ and https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/341#issuecomment-382648188, but fail all, small icon in my push notification still default of onesignal.

This is my folder structure and my script :

**My folder structure** :

[image]

**copy_android_notification_icons.js** :

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var rootDest = 'platforms/android/app/src/main/res';
var files = [{
    'icon_onesignal/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png':
        path.join(rootDest, 'drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png')
}, {
    'icon_onesignal/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png':
        path.join(rootDest, 'drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png')
}, {
    'icon_onesignal/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png':
        path.join(rootDest, 'drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png')
}, {
    'icon_onesignal/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png':
        path.join(rootDest, 'drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png')
}, {
    'icon_onesignal/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png':
        path.join(rootDest, 'drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png')
}];

function createFolder(pathAbsolute) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(pathAbsolute)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(pathAbsolute);
  }

  console.log('Folder ready ', pathAbsolute);
}

module.exports = function(context) {
  var root = context.opts.projectRoot;

  createFolder(path.join(root, rootDest, 'drawable-hdpi'));
  createFolder(path.join(root, rootDest, 'drawable-mdpi'));
  createFolder(path.join(root, rootDest, 'drawable-xhdpi'));
  createFolder(path.join(root, rootDest, 'drawable-xxhdpi'));
  createFolder(path.join(root, rootDest, 'drawable-xxxhdpi'));

  files.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      var src = path.join(root, key);
      var dest = path.join(root, obj[key]);

      if (fs.existsSync(src) && fs.existsSync(path.dirname(dest))) {
        fs.createReadStream(src).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));

        console.log('Copied ' + src + ' to ' + dest);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

**app.components.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      };

      window["plugins"].OneSignal
        .startInit("xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-123, "1234567")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
    });
  }
}
```

**config.xml**

```xml
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <hook src="hooks/copy_android_notification_icons.js" type="after_prepare" />
</platform>
```

Please correct my folder or my script, maybe you find a mistake and please help to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You could follow below steps. Then you no need to touch your platform folder and manually add push notification icons.

- Go to [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default) and generate icons using name
  **`ic_stat_onesignal_default`**
- Then copy those icons into android folder under resources. In my case
  it looks like below.

[image]

- Then in **`config.xml`** file add below code.

```xml
<!-- Add to your existing android platform sction -->
<platform name="android">      
    <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
</platform>
```

- Build the project
  again.

Now default push notification icon will replace with new one.

Find more details from [OneSignal DOC](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons)

Comment: Is there any way to create colored image as small icon instead of white ?

Comment: @Darshana, I managed to create colored icons by the following : 1- Generate the icons as in coder response. 2- Color each of the icons using Adobe Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

I was working in **OneSignal** last week and did the same as you. There are some specific sizes for the **Notification**.

Generate From Android Assets or online [here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit).

**Sizes must be set :**

```
Small Notification Icon (mdpi)- 24x24
Small Notification Icon (hdpi)- 36x36
Small Notification Icon (xhdpi)- 48x48
Small Notification Icon (xxhdpi) - 72x72
Small Notification Icon (xxxhdpi)-96x96
```

**Also**, Remember you have to put all icons on the platform folder. For this go to - `platform/android/app/src/main/res/` .

Create the drawable folder if not present there.  Name should be like - `drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi` and so on.

[image]

**Note** the name you are using for the **icon.**

**Now**, From the onesignal panel use the name in small icon options. Example

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue.