# Ionic OneSignal notification icon and sound

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I increased notifications in my app through the OneSignal plugin, I would like to customize the icon and sound of the notification, I followed the documentation, but it did not work.

What could I have done wrong?
Here is a print of my config.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qAow.png)

The code config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/sound/open-ended.mp3" target="platforms/android/res/raw/open-ended.mp3" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
```

the app.component.ts:

```
this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => {
  data.payload.sound = 'open-ended',
  data.payload.smallIcon = 'drawable-hdpi-icon'
});
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
  // do something when a notification is opened
});
this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

I'm using cordova-android:7.1.4, and onesignal-cordova-plugin:2.4.5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! You are more likely to receive support from the community if you post your code directly in the question rather than linking to some other location.

Comment: You need to do this on server end not on client end. This handler is to handle action on notification on client. Changing property inside it won't change anything. Check this https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Comment: But i pass in onesignal panel the sound name and not work. I'm test in OneSignal message panel

Comment: [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474275/how-to-change-default-push-notification-icon-to-small-icon-in-onesignal-in-ionic?answertab=active#tab-top)
how to send custom icon in one signal

Answer (score 0):

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/sound/mysound.wav" target="app/src/main/res/raw/mysound.wav" />
```

This is how i placed and it works. For Android 8+ you need to create notification category in onesignal settings

Comment: can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580338/change-notification-default-icon-in-onesignal-react-native)